# Quadratic Equation Program Outputs Incorrect Answer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm really tired, so I'm probably just forgetting something, but here it is. It's been a long time since I've even touched quadratics. The answers are totally off, for example:
2x**2 – 4x – 3 = 0 should result in  x = –0.58, x = 2.58. Instead, I get x=10, x=-2. I'm sure I'm doing something super basic wrong here.

```
    import math
    import sys
    a = float(input('a ='))
    b = float(input('b ='))
    c = float(input('c ='))
    cont = float(input('Continue? (1/0)'))
    a1 = int((-b + math.sqrt(b**(2)-4*a*c))/2*a)
    a2 = int((-b - math.sqrt(b**(2)-4*a*c))/2*a)
    if cont == 1:
        print(a)
        print(b)
        print(c)
        print(cont)
        print('x1 =',a1)
        print('x2 =', a2)

    elif cont == 0:
                 sys.exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parenthesis to your equation around (2*a):

```
a1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b**(2)-4*a*c))/(2*a)
a2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b**(2)-4*a*c))/(2*a)
```

Also, do you mean to convert to integer?

Comment: Converting to integer was a mistake, I wasn't thinking straight. Thanks for the help! I knew it would be something stupid.